# Is it possible to install Xcode 6 on Snow Leopard?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode6, osx-snow-leopard, legacy

I want to use Mac OS X 10.6.8 and the latest update of Xcode at the time of writing, which is Xcode 6.1. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. Xcode 6 requires OS X 10.9.3 or later or OS X 10.10 and cannot be installed on any version of OS X earlier than this. ([Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_6_0.html))